# Firestore collection if array contains item from another array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is it possible to query a firestore collection by seeing if an array contains a string from another array?

For example

```
   this.afs.collection<Sip>('microlearning', ref =>
          ref.where('organisationIds', 'array-contains', this.user.organisationIds));
```

where organisationIds is a list of strings.

Is this possible in one query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Have a similar requirement here.

Comment: Hi, I ended up having to loop through and do a query for every value. Wasn't the best solution but worked for our case.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Right now, arrayContains only works when searching the array for a single value. The best work-around I can think of would be to "pre-calculate" a value that you would store for common values that you might want ORed together.